# JFrame does not load On iOS

Tags: java, ios, swing

When trying to load a JFrame on iOS using jikes, it throws an awt error(cannot load awt toolkit) caused by an un satisfied link error(native library gtkeeper not found). This is the code:

```
 public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame{
     public Test(){
         super("foo");
         setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
         setVisible(true);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
         new Test();
     }
 }
```

Comment: iOS is for iPhone and iPad devices, since Java does not run on iOS, the question does not make sense

Comment: Well, there's your problem, Swing/AWT isn't designed to run on iOS platform and, as you have found, doesn't have the required native libraries to support it

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Swing application to a web platform with [Ajax Swing](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/). From there, all you have to do is put the converted application into a Web View.